# Is it possible to use something like JsonPath with kotlin JSON parsing

Tags: json, kotlin, jsonpath

I have a json structure that I need to (sort of) flatten when serializing it into an object. Some of the elements are at the top level and some are in a sub field. In addition, 1 of the fields is an array of space delimited strings that I need to parse and represent as `myString.splig(" ")[0]`

So, short of a `when` expression to do the job, can I use something like a [jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/tree/master/json-path/src/test/java/com/jayway/jsonpath) query to bind to certain fields? I have thought of even doing some kind of 2-pass binding and then merging both instances.

```json
{
  "key": "FA-207542",
  "fields": {
    "customfield_10443": {
      "value": "TBD"
    },
    "customfield_13600": 45,
    "customfield_10900": {
      "value": "Monitoring/Alerting"
    },
    "customfield_10471": [
      "3-30536161871 (SM-2046076)"
    ],
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Problem Mgmt - Corrective Action"
    },
    "created": "2022-08-11T04:46:44.000+0000",
    "updated": "2022-11-08T22:11:23.000+0000",
    "summary": "FA | EJWL-DEV3| ORA-00020: maximum number of processes (10000) exceeded",
    "assignee": null
  }
}
```

And, here's the data object I'd like to bind to. I have represented what they should be as `jq` expressions.

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class MajorIncident constructor(
    @SerialName("key")
    val id: String, // .key
    val created: Instant, // .fields.created
    val pillar: String, // .fields.customfield_10443.value
    val impactBreadth: String?,
    val duration: Duration, // .fields.customfield_13600 as minutes
    val detectionSource: String, //.fields.customfield_10900.value
    val updated: Instant, // .fields.updated
    val assignee: String, // .fields.assignee
    //    "customfield_10471": [
    //      "3-30536161871 (SM-2046076)"
    //    ],
    val serviceRequests: List<String>?, // .fields.customfield_10471 | map(split(" ")[0]) -
    @SerialName("summary")
    val title: String, //.summary
    val type: String, // .fields.issuetype.name // what are options?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlinx Serialization, I'm not sure there is any built-in support for jsonpath.

One simple option is to declare your Kotlin model in a way that matches the JSON. If you really want a flattened object, you could convert from the structured model into the flat model from Kotlin.

Another option is to write a custom serializer for your type.